# Required WebLogic 12.2.1 jar files for running jwsc ant task

Tags: java, ant, jar, jax-ws, weblogic12c

We have WebLogic Server 12.2.1 on a server, and I have my development done on my notebook. I am not able to install WebLogic on my notebook due to company policy. If I want to use the jwsc ant task on my notebook, what are the required JAR files that I need to copy from the server?

I have read about weblogic.jar, but this file contains only a single MANIFEST.MF file that includes class paths to other JAR files. I am sure that just copying weblogic.jar to my notebook is not enough to get jwsc task to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At minimum you need these jar files:

> wlHome/wlserver/modules/clients/com.oracle.webservices.wls.jaxws-wlswss-client.jar
>   wlHome/wlserver/modules/com.bea.core.repackaged.apache.xerces.jar
>   wlHome/wlserver/modules/com.bea.core.annogen.jar
>   wlHome/wlserver/modules/com.bea.core.xml.xmlbeans.jar
>   wlHome/wlserver/modules/com.bea.core.descriptor.j2ee.jar
>   wlHome/wlserver/modules/com.bea.core.xml.staxb.runtime.jar
>   wlHome/wlserver/modules/com.oracle.weblogic.application.jar
>   wlHome/wlserver/modules/com.bea.core.descriptor.application.jar
>   wlHome/wlserver/modules/com.bea.core.descriptor.application.binding.jar
>   wlHome/wlserver/modules/com.bea.core.beangen.jar
>   wlHome/wlserver/modules/com.bea.core.descriptor.settable.binding.jar
>   wlHome/wlserver/modules/com.bea.core.appdescriptor.jar
>   wlHome/wlserver/modules/com.oracle.weblogic.management.base.jar
>   wlHome/wlserver/modules/com.oracle.weblogic.management.upgrade.jar

You may need additional jars from wlHome/wlserver/modules depending on what WS features you want.

Comment: Hi George, I don't really need to run jwsc ant task now. Rather, I require the ant deploy/undeploy weblogic task. This task is in the class weblogic.ant.taskdefs.management.WLDeploy. Would you know all the required JAR files for the WebLogic ant deploy/undeploy task? Thanks.